# How to provide a password as a variable to zip protected file?

Tags: linux, password, zip

I wish to unzip it using a variable to pass the password - instead of being prompted.
I tried to use the parameter `-P` but it seems to be not working for me:

```
[ora@hp_01 ZIP]$ zip -qT -P oracle test_zip.zip *.xml
[zicPYwGa] test.xml password:
[orae@hp_01 ZIP]$
```

Comment: I'm a little confused which direction you're going. The title suggests that you have an existing password-protected zip file, the body continues by saying "wish to unzip it", but the command you give is "zip" (not "unzip") with the `-T` option saying to "test zipfile integrity". Which direction are you going and what commands are you using?

Comment: Yes - good question - create zip file -> tests it integrity -> add password via variable - this is exactly what I need or more generic question Is it possible to test integrity of the zip file without being prompted for the password?

Answer (score 0):

Use p7zip,

```
7z a test_zip.zip -p oracle *.xml
```

Comment: Given the Q's  mention of the 'zip' command, you might want to adjust the answer to output a "zip" format with  the `-t` flag.